# datetime string issue in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

Suppose I have following code to convert datetime to string:

```
DateTime dt;
//...
string ds = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
```

If the dt is 15/02/2009 08:22, I want to the string is 15/02/2009 08:22AM
If the dt is 15/02/2009 20:22, I want to the string is 15/02/2009 08:22PM

How to implement it?

Answer (score 13):

use this:

```
string ds = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmtt")
```

Here are all of the available options for [converting DateTime to string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

As per the documentation of [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx), the characters you need to add are t's, so this should work:

```
string ds = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmtt")
```

One 't' would give you 'P' or 'A', and two will give you 'PM' or 'AM'.

Note that depending on your current [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx), you might, or might not, get the AM/PM.

Answer (score 1):

you should use lowercase "t"...

```
DateTime dt;
//...
string ds = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmtt")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt;

string ds = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmtt");
```